# adding a background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a background in a widget from flutter, but it's not working:

```
home: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar("Form"),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/img/bluetransparent.png", fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(...............................
```

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Just close the parentesis to fix the issue:

```
image: AssetImage("assets/img/bluetransparent.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
```